# Transparent and borderless text-input

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I try to create login page contains username and password but i want rounded grouped inputs(username and password). I tried this:

```
border: none;
border-color: transparent;
```

using css, but still border is coming what might be error.

Comment: Can you show us your markup?

Comment: Inputs are well known for being difficult to style. Maybe using contenteditable divs would be better.

Comment: without jQM above code will work.

Comment: It is just normal input(type text) @ThOrndike.

Comment: can u share your markup and css??

Comment: see here http://jsfiddle.net/teledna123/6B7uE/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Solution 1

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/95Paz/

CSS used:

```
.ui-input-text {
    border: none !important;
    border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

### Solution 2

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/95Paz/1/

#### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" style="border:none" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"  name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username or Email" />
    <input type="password" style='border-radius:5px;' id="password" placeholder="Password" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#wrapper .ui-input-text {
    border: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

### More info

When working with jQuery Mobile you need to understand that final HTML content is enhanced and it don't look like previous one. Also when overrding classes !important must be used. Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**.

Comment: Can `!important` be avoided or are there inline styles?

Comment: There are two ways to avoid !important. 1. Manually change input css in jQuery Mobile structure file, 2. Wrap input fields into a div (or any other tag), give that tag an id and use it like this #wrapper_id .ui-input-text, this solution will not require !important.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the box as well, add "box-shadow: none;". http://jsfiddle.net/95Paz/2/

Comment: or `$('.ui-input-text').css({
    'border': 'none transparent'
});`.

Comment: thanks @Gajotres. unselect JQM framework then username filed how it will look i want in that way. Even after unselecting JQM framework here password is bordered.

Comment: and i don't want any rounded corners around the input. it should be too plain.

Comment: see here updated grouped one http://jsfiddle.net/teledna123/6B7uE/2/ but the problem is input corners it won't look good.

Comment: @sunmoon now you're talking about listview not only input. check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6B7uE/3/

Comment: Thanks @Omar But i want to create like this view Ex. touch.facebook.com login page.

Answer (score 3):

When using jQuery Mobile, you need to disable its auto-enhanced as follow

HTML

```
<input type='text' data-role='none'>
```

CSS

```
input, input:hover, input:focus, input:active {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  outline-offset: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```